# How to make square/sharp lines with Grease pencil?

Tags: grease-pencil

Every line ends up in either a fade or a circle.

You can sort of achieve it by scaling down the last point in the stroke, but you have to do it manually every time! and it only gets you a triangle instead.

Basically, I want to make a line as normal, but the corners and ends must be sharp. I cannot for the life of me figure how to do that.

With vector art is very simple but Blender can't do that.

Comment: for future reference screenshots really improve a post and help it to get good answers, but I think this question is really well described :)

Answer (score 2):

In the *Tool Settings*, enable the *Stabilize Stroke* option, then it keeps the ending caps of the stroke sharp.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, you want tapered straight lines?

When I tried this with default settings I got faded ends. But I found that this can be fixed if you:

- Turn Off **Strength Pressure** (*which should be all you need to do*)
- Adjust the **Thickness Profile** to move the outer Left & Right control points slightly up from the bottom of the graph (*which is least thickness*)

[image: Pressure & Thickness Profile adjustment]

Comment: Thank you for responding but that doesn't slove the issure ;-; ... I discoverd that feature too but it doesn't change the sharpness of the corners